# WCF Data Service whose data source is another WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

does someone know if it possible to use one WCF Data Service as data source of another WCF Data Service? If so, how?

Comment: Not horribly descriptive.  If you want the short answer, yes, you can have as many services and proxies going as you please.  Can you give an example of what you are thinking so we can give an example of how to do it?

Comment: there is a WCF Data Service in the intranet of my company that gives access to a data source, in this case SQL server. A public web server has access to this WCF Data Service. I am looking for the simplest way of giving access from internet to a subset of the entities of the WCF Data Service. The way i thought was setting up a second WCF Data Service in the public web server using like data source the first WCF Data Service

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just use a reverse proxy and use something like a QueryInterceptor or MessageInspector to do the additional filtering? I can elaborate if it would help.

Answer (score 1):

So the short answer is yes.  Actually I have consumed one WCF service in another (HttpBinding coming to a service on computer, then that service had a NamedPipesBinding service to communicate with multiple desktop apps, but it did some data transformation in the middle).  That would not be an issue at all, you would set up a proxy/client just like you would in a desktop client, and handle everything in your new service as if it was just passing information along, you could even create a shared library for the DataContracts and such.

**HOWEVER** I would not suggest the leapfrog method in your implementation.  Depending on how many customers you are potentially opening the door too, you may be introducing a bottlekneck, if you have a singleton service, or overload your existing service in the case of many connections from the new one.  Since you have a SQL server, why would you not have a WCF service on your web/app server (public) that connected to it and provided the data you need?  I'm only thinking this because your situation can become exponentially complicated when you start trying to pass credentials for authentication and authorization between the two, depending on your security settings.  Another thing to consider is the complexity in debugging this new service and the old one, and a client at the same time, as if it wasn't a pain just to do server and client, since you are opening it to a public facing port, there are different things to set up, and debugging everything on the same machine is not the same as a public facing application server.

Sorry if this goes against what you were hoping to hear.  I'm just saying that it *is* possible, but not suggested (at least by me) in your particular case.